# How can I see very old rankings in League of Legends

Tags: league-of-legends

I want to see what rank level I used to have 4 years ago in League of Legends, since I can't remember. Is there a way to see this? Maybe a website that holds all the data or something?

I already checked on www.leagueofgraphs.com but all my data seems to be gone. I don't have any rating there (haven't played for the past 4 years), it just knows that my account exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few. I use [op.gg](http://euw.op.gg/summoner/userName=XtremeBaumer)

This one refers to my own account and it goes back to season 3 (I already played in S1 but without ranking). Maybe there is another site which holds even more data.

List of websites:

- [Lolking](http://www.lolking.net)
- [lolprofile](https://www.lolprofile.net) (not tested)
- [lolskill](http://lolskill.net) (not tested)

Comment: Thank you for that list! I checked my account on all of them, but I don't have a ranking on any if the sites. Maybe my rankings are even from before Season 3 (4 years was just a wild estimation,it could also be 5 or even 6).

Comment: Could be due to some soft-reset. [Wasted on lol](https://wol.gg/) shows much less than the total I actually have. Maybe they wiped some data from older seasons and thats the reason we can't find earlier ones

Comment: I believe those sites store data from previous years, but if you never used them before season 4, they won't have any data on you. Season 4 is when Riot released their API and tried to get third parties to stop scraping games unofficially, and that's as far back as the API stores matches.